# Generics and events

Tags: c#, events, generics

I am making a game and I'm trying to create an way for objects to handle collisions with each other. I want to do something like:

```
//Imaginary C#

public SomethingThatCollides()
{
    CollisionEvent<ObjectA> += CollisionWithObjA;
    CollisionEvent<ObjectB> += CollisionWithObjB;
}

void CollisionWithObjA(ObjectA other)
{
    //Do something
}
void CollisionWithObjB(ObjectB other)
{
    //Do something else
}
```

When, say, `CollisionEvent<ObjectA>` is raised (perhaps by some collision checking code), `CollisionWithObjA` should get called. Same for `CollisionWithObjB`; when a collision with ObjectB is detected, it will raise the `CollisionEvent<ObjectB>` event which results in `CollisionWithObjB` getting called.

Is something like this possible?

Comment: its difficult to understand what you are trying to do. Do you mean when collision occurs you will call the 'SomethingThatCollides' method? Please provide more explanation

Comment: @Andrew: If I have objA, objB, and objC, all of them can collide with all of them??? Will there be collision methods for AB, AC, and BC?

Comment: Or is it a master A object that collides with all other, having no treatment for collision of others between themselves?

Comment: There could be, but for this case I only have AB and AC, and no BC

Answer (score 1):

Here is the thing, if class is generic and it has static field, it can work like a dictionary with key being type

```
public class Something {
    public class EventsHolder<T> 
    {
       static event Action<T> CollideEvent;
    }

    public void AddEvent<T>(Action<T> collisionEvent) 
    {
      EventsHolder<T>.CollideEvent = collisionEvent;
    }

    public void RaiseCollision<T>(T Obj)
    {
      var Event = EventsHolder<T>.CollideEvent;
      if (Event != null) Event(Obj);
    }
}
```

Downside is that it uses static fields which can be inapropriate. 
In this case you can use code @Daniel posted.

Comment: Hmm, sounds interesting, but I can't call `EventsHolder<T>.CollideEvent` from outside EventsHolder, how would I get around this?

Comment: Create a `CallEvent` static method inside EventsHolder to call the event. Now in `RaiseCollision` you call that method. (I edited the answer, but must wait revision from someone)

Comment: @AndrewSun Just make public method for doing it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really create a generic event like that. I suggest you create a special event arguments class that also encapsulates the collided object and check for its type in the event handler method:

```
public class CollisionEventArgs : EventArgs {
  public object Object {
    get; private set;
  }
  // ...
}
```

You'll need a special dispatcher method to use it:

```
class SomethingThatCollides {

  public SomethingThatCollides(CollisionManager cm) {
    cm.CollisionEvent += CollisionWithObj;
  }

  void CollisionWithObj(object sender, CollisionEventArgs args) {
    if (args.Object is ObjectA) {
      CollisionWithObjA((ObjectA)args.Object);
    }
    else if (args.Object is ObjectB) {
      CollisionWithObjB((ObjectB)args.Object);
    }
  }

  // ...
}
```

Or, you can try to solve this with double-dispatching, without using C# events. Look at [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatching) for a collision example.

Comment: The point was to create a separate method to handle each collision without unnecessary boxing and type checking. Is there really no way to do so?

Comment: Look at [double-dispatching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatching) on wikipedia.

Answer (score 0):

That's uggly, but...You could have a dicionary of events by type:

```
Dictionary<Type, object> MyEventsByType;

event Action<A> CollisionEventA;
event Action<B> CollisionEventB;
event Action<C> COllisionEventC;

void Initialize()
{
    MyEventsByType = new Dictionary<Type, object>();

    MyEventsByType.Add(typeof(A), CollisionEventA);
    MyEventsByType.Add(typeof(B), CollisionEventB);
    MyEventsByType.Add(typeof(C), CollisionEventC);
}

void RaiseCollision<T>(T Obj)
{
    Action<T> Event = (Action<T>)MyEventsByType[typeof(T)];
    if (Event != null) Event(Obj);
}
```